# Determine DBL_MIN in a loop

Tags: c++, double, precision

I tried to determine DBL_MIN in a loop (in order to test another issue) and I was surprised by the output:

```
double tmp(1.0);
double min(tmp);
while(tmp>0)
{
    tmp/=2.0;
    if(tmp>0) min=tmp;
        else break;
}

cout<<scientific<<endl;
cout<<"Computed minimum: "<<min<<endl;
cout<<"Defined minimum: "<<DBL_MIN<<endl;
if(min>0 && min<DBL_MIN) cout<<"min is between 0 and DBL_MIN, HUH!"<<endl;

exit(1);
```

The output is:

```
Computed minimum: 4.940656e-324
Defined minimum: 2.225074e-308
min is between 0 and DBL_MIN, HUH!
```

How can *min* hold the value 4.94e-324 when the smallest positive value is 2.2e-308 ? To my understanding positive values below DBL_MIN should not representable. Tested with GCC 4.9.2 on a Core i7 under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBL_MIN` is minimum **normalized** positive value of double. This means that this is the minimum value that has its mantissa not less than `1.0`. You can still go for smaller numbers if you choose smaller mantissa.

So what you get is [Denormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). As Wikipedia puts it,

> In a normal floating-point value, there are no leading zeros in the
>   significand; instead leading zeros are moved to the exponent. So
>   0.0123 would be written as 1.23 × 10<sup>−2</sup>. Denormal numbers are numbers where this representation would result in an exponent that is below
>   the minimum exponent (the exponent usually having a limited range).
>   Such numbers are represented using leading zeros in the significand.

The [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) governs the representation of `double` (and other floating-point types). The representation consists of exponent `e` and mantissa `m` (and sign bit, which is irrelevant for this question).

For the exponent `e` *not equal to zero*, the corresponding `double` value is

```
(1 + m/2^52) * 2^(e-1023)
```

(`^` stands for power, and 52 is the number of bits in `m`, so that `m/2^52` is always between 0 inclusive and 1 non-inclusive). The implicit (not included in `m`) `1` means that the minimal number that can be stored this way corresponds to `m==0` and `e==1` (remember that `e!=0` for this representation), which gives the value of

```
2^(-1022)
```

which is approx. `2.225074e-308`, that is `DBL_MIN`.

However, `e==0` is treated in a special way. For `e==0`, the implicit `1` is dropped, resulting in

```
(m / 2^52) * 2^(-1022)    // remember that e==0
```

This allows for representation of exact zero (with `m==0`), and also for subnormals (or denormals) for small `m`. The smallest possible such number is for `m==1`, that is `2^(-1074)`, or approx. `4.940656e-324`.